Expected number of steps to stop a range division game
Consider the range of positive integers $[1, N]$, which is the starting point of the game. At each step of the game, a number is chosen uniformly randomly from the current state of the array. If the selected number is $1$, the game is immediately stopped. Otherwise we divide the existing numbers (if divisible) by the smallest prime divisor of the selected number and continue the game.
For example, starting with $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}$, if we select $4$, it transforms into $\{1,1,3,2,5,3,7,4,9,5\}$.
What is the expected number of steps to finish the game for a given $N$?
I got these values from Monte-Carlo simulation:



[1,N]
Expected no. of steps




[1,10]
3.41


[1,100]
8.29


[1,1000]
16.19



Is there a faster way to calculate it (and better precision) for larger $N$? Perhaps we can obtain some sort of asymptotic expression for it? Any help is much appreciated.

What is the source of this problem?

@user2661923 I thought about the problem myself. Couldn't find similar type of problem on the internet.
